# Generalized questions allowed?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

We have [a question](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/3711/are-there-many-assembly-type-3d-printers) simply asking about the existence of a type of printer. This question does not appear to be revolving around recommendation. Personally, I feel that questions like this can be useful for branching out and learning about non-traditional 3D printing.

Whether these should be set as community-driven is another debate, but should we at least allow non-recommendation list questions?

Answer (score 1):

I think the question you reference is a good question for the site as it isn't opinion based and could have a specific answer, or even several answers. In this case if multiple people answered, the 'best' answer could either be seen as being the most descriptive, or detailed about the options listed.

Since 3D printing is still a fairly new field and is still expanding and changing, I think there is a good chance that this type of question will be more common, and to exclude them might be limiting. Moreover, allowing list type answers can still be updated as technologies change and evolve.